# Dividing with a bigger divisor

Tags: binary, binary-operations

I have a task with binary operations

> 10 ÷ 10011

I have trouble in solving this equation. I tried searching but i can't find one with same given values (where divisor is bigger than dividend).

> If the divisor is greater than the dividend, just proceed with the algorithm as is. Trailing zeros will be brought down to form the appropriate subproblems.

This is only what I got but i don't understand. Could it be that it's just an error?

Comment: Can you do long division with decimal numbers? For example $14$ divided by $93$?

Comment: @Servaes haven't thought abt that until now. I will try. Thanks

Comment: Just use $100000/10011 and divide the result by 1000